Cannot retrieve selected date value in Java backend from primefaces p:calendar
I have a primefaces p:calendar component, from which I select different dates.
I need to get the selected date value in Java, but none of the approaches I tried seems to work, as I always get a null object from the event. My code currenyly looks like below:
Xhtml:
<p:calendar id="inputField_#{assetDetail.sanitizeId(field.name)}"
value="#{assetDetail.dataFieldValuesMap[field.name]}"
pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" styleClass="datafield-value"
rendered="#{assetDetail.editMode}">
event="dateSelect" listener="#{assetDetail.creationDateChange}"/>
</p:calendar>

Java backend:
    public void creationDateChange(SelectEvent<Date> event) {
        Date selectedDate = event.getObject();
        if (selectedDate != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(selectedDate);
            System.out.println(formattedDate);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Event Object is null.");
        }
    }

The variable event.getObject() returns null every time, the method is being triggered right though, so I really cannot figure out where the problem is.
Can anyone help?

Not what you are asking, but first of all you should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. You need the LocalDate class. Its toString method will give you the output format you are after (yyyy-MM-dd). Date has design problems, SimpleDateFormat is notoriously troublesome, and both are outdated the last 10 years. Avoid them.

Note that p:calendar is deprecated. Use p:datePicker instead.

Also if you need examples that work just look at the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar/calendar.xhtml but you should consider moving to DatePicker.
